# Are the first ten zeros of this Dedekind zeta function non-simple?

Tags: nt.number-theory, zeta-functions, l-functions

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63544/computing-on-a-computer-the-first-few-non-trivial-zeros-of-the-zeta-function) 
asks about the zeros of the zeta function of the number field with defining
polynomial:

```
x^24 + 3*x^23 - 2*x^22 - 43*x^21 + 81*x^20 + 1579*x^19 + 2434*x^18 - 5192*x^17 + 4678*x^16 - 41425*x^15 + 423527*x^14 + 1352722*x^13 + 5199537*x^12 - 13364304*x^11 - 138065100*x^10 + 228783352*x^9 + 1254448448*x^8 - 3179566016*x^7 + 4205123840*x^6 + 139822208*x^5 - 31439415040*x^4 + 28607489536*x^3 + 330701977600*x^2 - 807251576832*x + 635017424896
```

I evaluated the derivative at the first few zeros on magma online.

According to Junkie's answer, the imaginary parts of the first zeros start:

```
 0
 0.99014365233
 1.38830360231
 2.35103235859
 3.45296629741
 4.32708276131
 4.73989005257
 5.42392092883
 5.99574967707
 6.70167394143
```

To my surprise, according to Magma online, the derivative is $0$ at $1/2$,
$O(10^{-12})$ at the approximation of the second zero,$O(10^{-10})$
at the third. At the rest it ranges between $O(10^{-8}),O(10^{-15})$.
At the approximations $\zeta_K(s)$ is about $10^{-25}$ at precision $50$.

Having in mind the given zeros are low precision approximations, these
small values might indicate non-simple zeros.

Riemann zeta appears at the factorization and at the first zeta
zero the derivative is large.

> Are the zeros really non-simple?
>
> If yes does this imply something for the number field?

So many small values appear more of a pattern than coincidence
to me.

[Magma online code](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)

```
Z1<x>:=PolynomialRing(Rationals());
p:=x^24 + 3*x^23 - 2*x^22 - 43*x^21 + 81*x^20 + 1579*x^19 + 2434*x^18 - 5192*x^17 + 4678*x^16 - 41425*x^15 + 423527*x^14 + 1352722*x^13 + 5199537*x^12 - 13364304*x^11 - 138065100*x^10 + 228783352*x^9 + 1254448448*x^8 - 3179566016*x^7 + 4205123840*x^6 + 139822208*x^5 - 31439415040*x^4 + 28607489536*x^3 + 330701977600*x^2 - 807251576832*x + 635017424896;
Nf<w>:=NumberField(p);
L:=LSeries(Nf : Precision := 50);
//a:=1/2+Sqrt(-1)*0.99014365233;
//a:=1/2+Sqrt(-1)*1.38830360231;
//a:=1/2+Sqrt(-1)*6.70167394143;
//a:=1/2 + Sqrt(-1)*14.134725141734693790457251983562470270;
a:=1/2;
fa:=Factorization(L);
fa;
L2:=fa[4][1];
Evaluate(L,a : Derivative:=1);
```

Comment: Look at what *L`prod* is, it will say that the $\zeta_K$ is itself a product of Artin reps, which don't need to appear to the first power. Namely, it is $\zeta_K=\zeta L_\chi L_{\bar\chi} A_2^2 A_{2,\chi}^2 A_{2,\bar\chi}^2 B_3^3$ with $A_2$ 2-dimensional and $B_3$ 3-dim so $24=1+1+1+2^2+2^2+2^2+3^2$, so unless you are looking for the roots of one of the 1-dim (Dirichlet) factors, you will have repeated roots. Note that $A_2$ has sign $-1$, this is the case of odd functional equation with even weight. I think $A_2$ is your example is http://www.lmfdb.org/ArtinRepresentation/2/26569/1/

Comment: I think the last line of your Magma code should have "L2" and not "L" if you want to replicate the computation you cited. It says "I compute its first few zeros for the 2-dimensional representation of real character", which is your L2.

Comment: @NAME_IN_CAPS I mean **L**, not **L2**. Isn't $L$ valid L-series?

Comment: @NAME_IN_CAPS L2 doesn't vanish at zeros AFAICT. It is the product that vanishes.

Comment: Oh, I see. Repeated roots are because of the exponents.

Comment: A similar phenomenon happens for the zeta-function of any number field $K$ that is Galois over $\mathbf Q$ such that ${\rm Gal}(K/\mathbf Q)$ is non-abelian: $\zeta_K(s) = \prod_{\rho} L(s,\rho)^{d_\rho}$, where $\rho$ runs over the different (that is, non-isomorphic) irreducible representations of ${\rm Gal}(K/\mathbf Q)$ and $d_\rho$ is the dimension of $\rho$. When ${\rm Gal}(K/\mathbf Q)$ is non-abelian, *some* $d_\rho$ is greater than 1, so every zero of $L(s,\rho)$ has multiplicity at least $d_\rho$ as a zero of  $\zeta_K(s)$, and thus is a non-simple zero of $\zeta_K(s)$.