# Double zero at $1/2$ of zeta function of number field

Tags: nt.number-theory, zeta-functions

Ten years old question asks about [Computing (on a computer) the first few (non-trivial) zeros of the zeta function of a number field](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63544/computing-on-a-computer-the-first-few-non-trivial-zeros-of-the-zeta-function).

Let $K$ be the number field with the degree 24 defining polynomial

```
 x^24 + 3*x^23 - 2*x^22 - 43*x^21 + 81*x^20 + 1579*x^19 + 2434*x^18 - 5192*x^17 + 4678*x^16 - 41425*x^15 + 423527*x^14 + 1352722*x^13 + 5199537*x^12 - 13364304*x^11 - 138065100*x^10 + 228783352*x^9 + 1254448448*x^8 - 3179566016*x^7 + 4205123840*x^6 + 139822208*x^5 - 31439415040*x^4 + 28607489536*x^3 + 330701977600*x^2 - 807251576832*x + 635017424896
```

and $\zeta_K$ be the zeta function of $K$.

According to computations with Magma online $\zeta_K$ has
double zero at $1/2$, but this could be numerical
instability with low precision.

> Q1 Does $\zeta_K$ really have double zero at $1/2$?

> Q2 Does the double zero implies some properties of $K$?

> Q3 Is there construction of number fields which have double
> or higher order zeros of zeta function at $1/2$?

In comment, David E Speyer suggested $L(s,\chi)^2$ should divide $\zeta_K$.

We believe that all zeros of $L(s,\chi)$ will be double zeros of $\zeta_K$.

Checking the first three zeros of the linked question (they are with
very low precision) give $|\zeta_K(\rho)| \sim 10^{-22}$
and $|\zeta_K'(\rho)| \sim 10^{-11}$. This numerical results
appear to suggest that the first three complex zeros are double.

> Q4 Are there other, preferably infinitely many, double zeros of
> $\zeta_K$?

Magma [online](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) code
in case someone is interested:

```
 Z1<x>:=PolynomialRing(Integers());
 p1:=x^24 + 3*x^23 - 2*x^22 - 43*x^21 + 81*x^20 + 1579*x^19 + 2434*x^18 - 5192*x^17 + 4678*x^16 - 41425*x^15 + 423527*x^14 + 1352722*x^13 + 5199537*x^12 - 13364304*x^11 - 138065100*x^10 + 228783352*x^9 + 1254448448*x^8 - 3179566016*x^7 + 4205123840*x^6 + 139822208*x^5 - 31439415040*x^4 + 28607489536*x^3 + 330701977600*x^2 - 807251576832*x + 635017424896;
 Nf<w>:=NumberField(p1);
 L:=LSeries(Nf);
 I:=Sqrt(-1);
 //t0:=0.99014365233;
 //t0:=1.38830360231;
 t0:=2.35103235859;
 A:=1/2+I*t0;
 Evaluate(L,A);
 Evaluate(L,A : Derivative:=1);
```

Comment: Is this field Galois?

Comment: Kevin Buzzard asked a question about this polynomial earlier https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63544 . According to him, it is Galois with Galois group $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$.

Comment: Here is a suggestion: This group has a two-dimensional irrep $\chi$ with real character values https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/SL(2,3).html . Then $L(s,\chi)^2$ should divide $\zeta_K$, so it would be enough to show that $L(1/2, \chi)=0$. Moreover, as $\chi$ is real valued, one should (if my guess is right) be able to use the intermediate value theorem to show that $L(s, \chi)$ has an odd number of zeroes in $(0,1)$, after which the functional equation should force $L(1/2, \chi)$ to vanish.

Comment: J.V. Armitage, *Zeta functions with a zero at $s=1/2$*, Inv. Math. 15, 199–205 (1971). https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01404125 The point is that some of the constituent Artin representations have an odd sign of functional equation. There is an example in the Magma Handbook (largely due to Serre in its construction). http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1585#18264

Comment: To summarize the straightforward parts: If $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois with Galois group $G$, and $\chi$ is a irreducible character of $G$, then there is an Artin L-function $L(s,\chi)$, which is holomorphic (except for a pole at $s=1$ if $\chi$ is the trivial character). We have $\zeta_K = \prod_{\chi} L(s, \chi)^{\chi(1)}$. So a zero of $L(s, \chi)$ makes a $\chi(1)$-fold zero of $\zeta_K$.

Comment: Now, $L(s,\chi)$ has a function equation which involves the "global root number" $W(\chi)$; if $\chi$ is real valued and $L(s,\chi)$ vanishes to order $k$ at $1/2$, then $W(\chi) = (-1)^k$.  So, if $W(\chi) = -1$, then $L(s,1/2)=0$. It is known that, if the corresponding irrep of $G$ is defined over $\mathbb{R}$, then $W(\chi)=1$. Frolich (1972) gives a criterion for $W(\chi)=-1$ when $G$ is the quaternion $8$-group and $\chi$ is the $2$-dimensional rep https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=323759 .

Comment: On skimming Mathscinet, I didn't see a condition for $W(\chi)=-1$ and $\chi(1)$ large, which would be the natural approach to answer Q3.

Comment: I'd expect a symplectic representation has a 50% chance of having odd functional equation, though proving it would be nontrivial. So maybe a subpart of Q3 is to show that there are symplectic irreps (of realized Galois groups) of arbitrarily large degree.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I edited asking about other double zeros. If $L(s,\chi)^2$ should divide $\zeta_K$, we believe all zeros of $L(s,\chi)$ will be double zeros of $\zeta_K$ and we get numerical evidence with the zeros of the linked question.

Comment: @user334725 I edited asking about other double zeros. If $L(s,\chi)^2$ should divide $\zeta_K$, we believe all zeros of $L(s,\chi)$ will be double zeros of $\zeta_K$ and we get numerical evidence with the zeros of the linked question.