# Consequences of infinitely many double zeros of zeta function of number field

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, zeta-functions

Related to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404462/double-zero-at-1-2-of-zeta-function-of-number-field) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63544/computing-on-a-computer-the-first-few-non-trivial-zeros-of-the-zeta-function).

Let $K$ be the number field with the degree 24 defining polynomial

```
 x^24 + 3*x^23 - 2*x^22 - 43*x^21 + 81*x^20 + 1579*x^19 + 2434*x^18 - 5192*x^17 + 4678*x^16 - 41425*x^15 + 423527*x^14 + 1352722*x^13 + 5199537*x^12 - 13364304*x^11 - 138065100*x^10 + 228783352*x^9 + 1254448448*x^8 - 3179566016*x^7 + 4205123840*x^6 + 139822208*x^5 - 31439415040*x^4 + 28607489536*x^3 + 330701977600*x^2 - 807251576832*x + 635017424896
```

and $\zeta_K$ be the zeta function of $K$.

According to an answer in the second question and Magma:

$\zeta_K=\zeta\cdot L(\omega)\cdot L(\bar\omega)\cdot L(\tau_2)^2\cdot
L(\tau_2\omega)^2\cdot L(\tau_2\bar\omega)^2\cdot L(\kappa_3)^3$

Zero of each factor of multiplicity greater than one
is a double or triple zero of $\zeta_K$.

> Q1 Does the infinitely many double zeros imply some properties of $K$?

> Q2 Why should one care about the simplicity of the zeros of Riemann
> zeta function in light of these double zeros?

Comment: For Q2, usually one considers *primitive* $L$-functions, and the only Dedekind $\zeta$-function that is primitive is that for the rationals. So the fact that $\zeta_K$ for general $K$ can have higher order zeros (due to primitive factors occurring with high multiplicity) is not so relevant.

Comment: Those double zeros are artificial, because they are coming from an $L$-function that appears inside the zeta-function of $K$ with multiplicity greater than $1$.  It's sort of like asking if the repeated prime factors in a perfect square $n^2$ for $n > 1$ could imply some property of prime numbers.  What *is* interesting are higher-order (meaning not of order $1$)  nontrivial zeros for an $L$-function that does not (or is at least not expected to) decompose into other $L$-functions; such phenomena do happen in the setting of the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture.

Comment: @KConrad In your example with $n^2$ I have the properties "never prime" and "always squareful", which would be an answer to the question.

Answer (score 5):

A1:  The existence of zeros of high multiplicity for $\zeta_K(s)$ is connected to whether the analogue of [Mertens's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_conjecture) for $K$ is true.  See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.06665).

A2:  The simplicity of the zeros of $\zeta(s)$, or any other **irreducible** $L$-function, is of great interest.  For example, the simplicity of the zeros of $\zeta(s)$ is a hypothesis (along with the Riemann Hypothesis) in a theorem due to [Rubinstein and Sarnak](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/experimental-mathematics/volume-3/issue-3/Chebyshevs-bias/em/1048515870.full) whose conclusion is that the logarithmic density of real numbers $x>0$ such that $\mathrm{Li}(x)>\pi(x)$ is

$0.99999973\ldots$

Similar bias questions can be posed with other $L$-functions.  Weaker (but still quite interesting) conclusions can be drawn using weaker hypotheses (such as bounded multiplicity of zeros instead of simplicity).  See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.8011v1) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.06394), for example.  But it seems to be the case that one needs the full simplicity hypothesis to achieve the above logarithmic density.

Comment: By irreducible L-function, do you mean primitive element of the Selberg class?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN I mean an L-function that does not factor as a product of L-functions of smaller degree.

Comment: Ok, so that's the same notion.